# How to invert the elements of an array?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am a beginner to c programming. I tried to write a code to invert the elements of an array. Here is what I have written

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a[5], i, j, b[5], k=5;
    printf("enter 5 numbers");
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    for(i=1;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=k; j>=1; j--)
        {
            b[j] = a[i];
            k--;
            break;
        }
    }

    for(j=1; j<5; j++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",b[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In output I am getting only 3 numbers inverted and not all 5.
Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Emmm... aren't you suppose to store the elements first, seperately?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you!! I mean I have used scanf ,right?

Comment: Eh. ignore it. got messed up in indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not really need a loop inside a loop. It can be done easily with one:

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    b[i] = a[4-i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all array index begins from `0` not from `1`. So if you declare array of size say 4 then valid index are from 0 - 3. For more clear understanding of this see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm

Now what you are trying to do can be done with single loop only! Like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int a[5],i,j,b[5],k=5;
    printf("enter 5 numbers");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    //see this :
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)// runs from 0 to 4
    {
        int bIndex = 4 - i;//get index of array b to store element of array a
        b[bIndex] = a[i];
    }

    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",b[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a[5], i, j, b[5], k=5;
    printf("enter 5 numbers");
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    `for(i=0;i<5;i++)`//see here begin
    {
       `for(j=5-k; j>=0; j++)` 
        {
            b[j] = a[i];
            k--;
            break;
        }
    }
    `for(j=0; j<5; j++)`
    {
        printf("%d\n",b[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, your first problem is in the loop condition written as

```
  for(j=k; j>=1; j--)
```

where you use `j` for indexing. This makes `b[j]` off-by-one. You should change it to

```
  for(j=k-1; j >= 0; j--)
```

That said,

```
        k--;
        break;
```

inside the loop is also wrong. Actually you don't need two loops there. Simplify as below.

```
 for(i=k-1, j =0; j < k; j++, i--)  //j goes up, i goes down.
 {
     b[j] = a[i];
 }

 for(j=0; j<5; j++)               //j starts from 0.....
 {
    printf("%d\n",b[j]);
 }
```

Comment: thanks for answering.....but still I am getting only numbers inverted instead of 5

Comment: No need for all this. Look at eyalm answer. So simple.

Comment: @TonyTannous and I decide to change my array size and the program blows up... :)